# Windowsform UI gets unresponsive even with background worker

Tags: datagridview, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a Windows from application using C#
in this form I have a button which retrieves data from a couple of tables in MSSQL and displays it in a DataGridView.  I have used a Background worker to get the view and I have a progressbar that I ant to set to marquee to show the user that something is happening, but even though I have the Data retrieval code in the DoWork method, the ProgressBar is unresponsive, here is some of the code

```
The button calls the fillData() method and that method is as follows

public void fillData()
        {
            if (ConnectionString == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must connect to the server first", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
            toolStripProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            toolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
```

//....some more code here  and then...

```
                System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundworker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
                backgroundworker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
                backgroundworker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundworker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

                backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

then I have the DoWork method

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Data.Tables.Clear();
        Data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter masterDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, conn);
        masterDA.Fill(Data, "ORDERS");
    }
```

and the RunWorkerCompleted

```
    private void backgroundworker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        ordersDGV.DataSource = Data.Tables[0];
        recordnoTSSL.Text = ordersDGV.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

but as soon as the background worker is called the UI gets unresponsive, I thought that this technique would allow me to show the progressbar and keep the UI responsive, 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to solve this.

1: Getting a datatable async from sql doesnt require a background worker. With SqlCommand BeginExecuteReader you're able to get data async, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx

2: You should never do cross-thread calls in the DoWork method. Create a dataset in the DoWork and set it as the result. In the RunWorkerCompleted you can assign the dataset or datatable as datasource:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter masterDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, conn);
    masterDA.Fill(dataSet, "ORDERS");
    e.Result = dataSet;
}

private void backgroundworker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Error != null )
    {
        // handle exception
    }
    var dataSet = e.Result;
    ordersDGV.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
}
```